# Automatically fill in wildcard tags

Tags: discussion, feature-request, tags, new-nav, tag-watching

In my "Favourite Tags" (the tag list you can create on the right hand side of a page) I have a few wildcards, for example:

[image]

It would be nice if the new tabs feature could pre-fill or save a wildcard such as `iis*` automatically rather than me having to select each tag in the suggestion drop down:

[image]

Even after just three tags it's a wee bit tedious.

Comment: It also would be nice because any new tags are automatically added,  instead of needing to add 'iis-9' when we realize we aren't picking up near tags

Comment: That's one of the reasons why I wild card.

Comment: another wildcard related request: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/362125

Comment: and another: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/362543

Comment: last one i promise: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/363139