# Sidebar layout issue when navigating using wildcard [tag-*]

Tags: bug, tags, design, sidebar

I often use wildcard searching on tags when looking for content on the site: [[sql-server*]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-server*).

This ends up producing a sidebar that looks a little like this (emphasis mine):

[image]

You can probably see where I'm going with this. It would make more sense for this to be organised like so (unless I'm missing something):

[image]

Or the best option, which would likely require a more than a design/layout change, would be to figure out that the user searched using a wildcard and show them that:

[image]

Both of these suggestions would free up space and show more of the other sidebar content... and when I say sidebar content, I mean ads... you know, the stuff that pays to keeps the lights on :-)

Comment: Unrelated to this, but note that you only get the 20 most popular tags (just like when searching on `/tags`) when using wildcards, not all tags

Comment: @AndrewT. thanks, wasn't aware of that, but I can live with that filter in my life.

Comment: Yeah this seems like a very specific bug. In some cases it is created as such a grid and in other cases (probably long keywords --> autoadjusting) it is created as a list...