# Allow wildcard [tag*] filters in the review queues

Tags: feature-request, tags, review-queues, filtering

When I filter questions on the site, I tend to use tags with wildcards: [**[sql-server*]**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-server*)

In the review queues, I just tried to do the same, but the wildcard functionality doesn't appear to work there. It might help reviewers with tag preferences/specialities review a greater number of posts if wildcard support was added.

At present, if you try to add a wildcard, it just trims it off when you click <kbd>Okay</kbd>.

[image]

Comment: That would be useful. It would probably require lifting the 3 tag restriction to be useful/avoid further frustration. I don't know why that limit exists, however. I'll ask around.

Comment: @JonEricson AFAIK, performance.

Comment: @Braiam Makes no sense. The review queue tag filter only needs to fetch one post at a time. It should be categorically more performant than the main search. I guess it needs to fetch more *related* data than the main search? But the query should be designed to only reach out to those tables *after* it's filtered by the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: Other requests to make the review queue filter more useful: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358559/1394393, https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/262383/1394393 And these would probably be more robust.

Comment: @jpmc26 https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/299920/792066 and that's for a count.

Comment: @Braiam That was 2 years ago on a holiday, and a count needs to load many rows. A properly indexed "fetch the next review" should only need to load 1 post plus related rows. Filtering by tag might make it read a number of tag rows, but it should quickly narrow down when joining to posts. So still faster than the main search, which notably includes a count.

Comment: @jpmc26 "They'll remain off until someone has time to **fix the underlying problem**." If that underlying problem isn't fixed, how would you expect that more complex queries would behave?

Comment: ["we designed the review system at a time when there was essentially no one reviewing; the notion of having a hundred active reviewers per day sounded pretty good. We've scaled waaay beyond that."](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/6120627#6120627) — Shog9 someone might want to go through the context (like @JonEricson)